# How to receive online/offline events in Javascript that's executed inside WKWebView on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an iOS app that uses WKWebView to load in local HTML/JS file that contains `online`/`offline` event listeners but they aren't fired when user loses/regains connection. Same HTML/JS works on Android.

`offline` event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/offline_event
`online` event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/online_event

Is there something specific I need to configure for it to trigger those events?

```js
window.addEventListener('online', () => {
    console.log('Regained internet connection');
});

window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
    console.log('Lost internet connection');
});
```

Comment: Without any code it is impossible to know what you are trying to do. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does it work as expected for non-local HTML file?

Comment: It doesn't work on iOS when loaded externally either. I'll prepare an example in a moment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found what solved it for me. I had to wait for the page to load in before attaching the event listeners like below instead of adding them as soon as script executes.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {

    window.addEventListener('online', () => {
        console.log('Regained internet connection');
    });

    window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
        console.log('Lost internet connection');
    });

)};
```